# Best Practices for SQL Statements/Connections in Get() Request

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

For simple lookups, I need to perform some SQL statements on a DB2 machine.  I'm not able to use an ORM at the moment.  I have a working example through this code, however **I'm wondering if it can be optimized more as this would essentially create a connection on each request.**  And that just seems like bad programming.

Is there a way I can optimize this Get() request to leave a connection open?  Nesting `using` statements seems dirty, as well.  How should I handle the fact that `Get()` really wants to return an object of User no matter what; even in error?  Can I put this connection in the start of the program so that I can use it over and over again?  What are some of the best practices for this?

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    String constr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB2Connection"].ConnectionString;

    public User Get([FromUri] User cst)
    {
        if (cst == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        else
        {
            using (OdbcConnection DB2Conn = new OdbcConnection(constr))
            {
                DB2Conn.Open();
                using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand(
                    // Generic SQL Statement
                    "SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE customerNumber = ?", DB2Conn))
                {
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var", cst.customerNumber);

                    using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                cst.name = (string)reader["name"];

                                return cst;
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return cst;
        }
    }
}
```

I found a [great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458598/a-new-sql-connection-for-each-query) that doesn't really have detailed answers, I feel like similar solutions exist for both of these questions...

Comment: Consider [setting ODBC connection pooling options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709288(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And that just seems like bad programming.

Why do you think that?

The underlying system should be maintaining connections in a connection pool for you.  Creating a connection should be *very* optimized already.

From a logical perspective, what you're doing now is exactly what you want to be doing.  Create the connection, use it, and dispose of it immediately.  This allows other threads/processes/etc. to use it from the connection pool now that you're done with it.

This also avoids the *myriad* of problems which arise from manually maintaining your open connections outside of the code that uses them.

> Is there a way I can optimize this Get() request to leave a connection open?

Have you *measured* an actual performance problem?  If not, there's nothing to optimize.

And there's a *very good chance* that hanging on to open connections in a static context in your web application is going to have *drastic* performance implications.

---

In short... You're already doing this correctly.  (Well, except for that unnecessary try/catch.  You can remove that.)

---

**Edit:** If you're just looking to improve the readability of the code (which itself is a matter of personal preference), this seems readable to me:

```
public User Get([FromUri] User cst)
{
    if (cst == null)
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

    using (var DB2Conn = new OdbcConnection(constr))
    using (var com = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE customerNumber = ?", DB2Conn))
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var", cst.customerNumber);
        DB2Conn.Open();
        using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                cst.name = (string)reader["name"]
                return cst;
            }
    }
    return cst;
}
```

Note that you can further improve it by re-addressing the logic of that SQL query.  Since you're fetching *one value* from *one record* then you don't need to loop over a data reader.  Just fetch a single literal and return it.  Note that this is free-hand and untested, but it might look something like this:

```
public User Get([FromUri] User cst)
{
    if (cst == null)
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

    using (var DB2Conn = new OdbcConnection(constr))
    using (var com = new OdbcCommand("SELECT name FROM [TABLE] WHERE customerNumber = ? FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY", DB2Conn))
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var", cst.customerNumber);
        DB2Conn.Open();
        cst.name = (string)com.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    return cst;
}
```

Comment: I suppose another part to this question is setting up a connection pool, currently researching @Bas' link.  Would you recommend anything other than that resource?

Comment: I mentioned `And that just seems like bad programming.` because of all the excessive nesting.  Removing that try/catch helped... but three `using`s in a row just seemed a bit odd, unless that's exactly what an ORm will do...

Comment: @ShawnStrickland: That seems like a good enough place to start.  And it links to more information as well.

Comment: Connection pools are set up automatically - you don't need to do anything.  You can _configure_ the pool (max connections, etc.) but you don't need to do anything to set one up.

Comment: @ShawnStrickland: If the method grows in size then you can refactor and pull out some private helper methods.  Just be careful not to allow connections and whatnot to cross contexts (basically, avoid `static` at all costs in this situation).  Nesting `using` statements itself isn't a bad thing at all.  You may be able to make the code more readable, but the structure is fine.

Comment: @ShawnStrickland Also your try/catch is pointless since it just re-throws the exception.  It;s the same thing that would happen without a try/catch at all.  Don't catch the exception unless you can _do something_ about it.  That removes one level of nesting :)

Comment: @ShawnStrickland: I've updated the answer with some potential refactoring to hopefully help make the code more readable for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

@David's answer addresses your actual questions perfectly but here's some other observations that may make your code a little more pallatable to you:

- remove the try/catch block - all you're doing is re-throwing the exception which is what will happen if you don't use a try/catch at all.  Don't catch the exception unless you can *do something* about it.  (I see now that @David's answer addresses that - either it was added after I read it or I missed it - my apologies for the overlap but it's worth reinforcing)
- Change your query to just pull `name` and use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader`.  You are taking the `name` value from the first record and exiting the `while` loop.  `ExecuteScalar` returns the value from the first column in the first record, so you can eliminate the `while` loop and the `using` there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, really good to know about `ExecuteScalar` as well.  In all honesty, this code is pulling lots of records from the table, but for single-lookups I'll definitely use `ExecuteScalar` in the future.